# React router does not render page after refresh page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I'm creating an simple admin panel with react. For developing and building this project I use snowpack.
In index.jsx file I have this:

```
<Router basename="admin">
 <Switch>
  <Route path="/pages" component={Pages} />
  <Route exact path="/login" component={Login} />
 </Switch>
</Router>
```

And in Pages.jsx I have this:

```
<div className="container">
  <BrowserRouter>
  <div className="pages">
    <h2>Pages</h2>
    <Switch>
    {
      pages.length !== 0
      ? pages.map(page => {
        return <Route exact key={page.id} path={'/admin/pages/' + page.path}><Page /></Route>
      })
      : null
    }
    </Switch>
    </BrowserRouter>
</div>
```

Pages I get from the server.
Application is work. And if I use 'http://example.com/admin' I can refresh and react render container (HTML block which I didn't add, cause it's not an issue), but if I refresh on all pages except 'http://example.com/admin' I get:

[image: 1]

```
GET http://localhost:8081/admin/index.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
```

snowpack.config.mjs:

```
/** @type {import("snowpack").SnowpackUserConfig } */

export default {
  mount: {
    dist: "/",
    src: "/"
  },
  routes: [
    {
      match: 'routes',
      src: '.*',
      dest: '/index.html',
    },
  ],
  plugins: [
    "@snowpack/plugin-sass",
    "@snowpack/plugin-react-refresh",
    "@snowpack/plugin-dotenv",
  ]
}
```

What I could change or add to fix this?
P.S. Login page also don't render after refresh

Comment: I don't understand if the site is really being hosted on `example.com` and trying to find a file on `localhost:8081`, or if `localhost:8081` was just replaced with `example.com` for simplicity in the question.

Comment: Exactly for simplicity. I replaced and removed unimportant stuff and concentrated on the problem.